# API sample request ends with error 'could not connect'

Tags: javascript, php, api, curl, events

If someone was using the Football-data.org API please help me with this error below. Why it couldn't connect ? Do I need to configure something first ?

[image: Error message]

Comment: that's crazy i am just looking at using the same api, let me look for you now

Comment: Maybe it is something wrong with the PORT:80 I am using ?

Comment: that's what I was thinking too. Maybe try 8080. There aint much in the docs

Comment: Now with '8080' it is: `504 Gateway Time-out
nginx/1.6.2`. Any ideas ?

Comment: have you put the `api_token.txt` in your `football-data-events` folder? you could email the guy and he will respond - Daniel@football-data.org

Comment: I have send him a message - thanks. I put the `api_token.txt` inside `football-data.events`(with dot) folder.

Comment: good man! hopefully you get it sorted!